# Composited Render is Different from the Viewer

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

Wondering what's going wrong here, the image that the viewer shows is what I want, yet the render after compositing looks different and in a way that doesn't seem to make sense. What I want to do is have a transparent object that also visually blocks whatever's behind it, is there a different way to achieve this?[image]